# Blank screen after boot menu during debian install

Tags: debian

I'm trying to install the latest Debian on a brand new computer, but to no avail so far. I've installed many flavors of Linux on many machines in the past, but this time it just won't work.

The machine has a Core i7 processor and 2x GeForce GTX 1080 GPUs. Each of them is connected to a screen with an HDMI cable (there's nowhere to plug the screens directly on the motherboard).

What happens is that whenever I select an option on the boot menu (i.e. graphical install), the screen turns blank. There's a signal, as it doesn't go to sleep, but no matter how long I wait, nothing appears. I'm assuming that this is related to Debian not having free drivers for the latest nVidia GPUs?

Is there a way I could still install Debian on this machine?
Would it work if I took out the hard drive, installed the OS from another computer and plugged it back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to install the OS. The issue was, as suspected, that drivers for the 1080 series are not present in the kernel yet.

To bypass this issue, I installed Debian on the hard drive from another machine, manually added the Nvidia drivers then put the drive back in the original machine!